# issue while using groovy script in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am using a groovy script to remove content from a Prop file in jenkins job. I am using groovy plugin in Build section. My code works fine when the value is hard coded. but when I am using a variable to pass the value,I am not getting desired result. I have tested my code in intelliji editor and is getting some result. Could you please help me understand what am I doing wrong?

**This is working fine**

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("C:\\AppianDeployment\\Application.properties")
Properties prop = new Properties()
String removeApps =  "AP2"
prop.load(input)
def keyToRemove = "${removeApps}".toString()
*prop.remove("AP1")*
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("C:\\AppianDeployment\\Application.properties");
prop.store(output, null);
```

**This is not working**

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("C:\\AppianDeployment\\Application.properties")
Properties prop = new Properties()
String removeApps =  "AP2"
prop.load(input)
def keyToRemove = "${removeApps}".toString()
*prop.remove(${keyToRemove})*
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("C:\\AppianDeployment\\Application.properties");
prop.store(output, null);
```

Comment: `prop.remove( removeApps )` should be enough. Because `removeApps` already a string.

Comment: @daggett it can be tricky if it's a GString

Answer (score 1):

There's no such literal in Groovy

```
prop.remove(${keyToRemove})
```

Instead you should be using either

```
prop.remove keyToRemove
```

or for whatever reason

```
prop.remove "${keyToRemove}".toString()
```